# shows a specific value in MVC DropDownList that matchs a viewbag value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do have a Html.DropDownListFor in a MVC C# App whre the user can selects specific values(years: 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020) as shows below

```
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correlativo2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Seleccione</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.correlativo2, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2018", Value = "2018" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2019", Value = "2019" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2020", Value = "2020" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2021", Value = "2021" } }, "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idEjercicio", @title = "especifique ejercicio de licitación", @Value = ViewBag.ejercicio })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correlativo2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

since the values are constant(years) and wont change(neither depends on any other value) I dont query the database to specify the values of the dropdownlist but it can happens that the `@Value = ViewBag.ejercicio` has a specific value (for instance: 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020) so I want the dropdownlist to show the year that match the value but it shows nothing even if the Viewbag has a value.

Ths is the ViewBag: `ViewBag.ejercicio = Convert.ToString(datos.correlativo2);` could you please help me

Comment: Why not set the value of model.correlativo2 to ViewBag.ejercicio ?

Comment: Thanks.That's what I did: ViewBag.ejercicio = Convert.ToString(datos.correlativo2)...if you didn't mean that I didn't understand your suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `Selected` property and using `DropDownList` instead:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correlativo2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Seleccione</span>
        @{
            var years = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2018", Value = "2018" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2019", Value = "2019" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2020", Value = "2020" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2021", Value = "2021" } };
            foreach (var year in years) 
            {
                year.Selected = year.Value == ViewBag.ejercicio;
            }
        }

        @Html.DropDownList("correlativo2", years, "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idEjercicio", @title = "especifique ejercicio de licitación" })
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correlativo2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

But it is indeed better to set value of the model property as @AndrewReyes suggested. Then Razor will automatically set selected value for you.

Comment: such a great solution

Comment: This is not correct. When binding to a model property, its the value of the property that determines what is selected. Internally the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aGKT4Q) an note that the `Selected` property is `true` for `2017`  but `2018` is selected because that is the value of the property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, your example makes sense, thanks, and that's what I suggested in last part. But my example is correct because I don't use value from the model, but `DropDownList` instead. And it works correctly. It is legal another way of creating select lists. Have a try yourself.

Comment: No, its you who need to try it! Your example does not work, and I have [forked the DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aX0OWr) to prove it. And if you want to learn how model binding works (i.e. it works by binding to the model property) then you can study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs). The only time the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is respected is when using `DropDownList("NotAPropertyOfTheModel", ....` or in the special case when used in a loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes, you are right, then it is weird why original code caused issues for PabloTobar. Because it fiddle it also works. Maybe it depends on MVC version?

Comment: MVC-2 to MVC-5 are all the same with regard to that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, then something is different in PabloTobar's implementation if his solution didn't work for him and mine is working. Thanks for posting correct solution. Consider to post it as answer as well.